# Trying to connect presto in tableau

Tags: presto, tableau-api

I am trying to connect presto in Tableau with catalog as cassandra. It gets connected but i am not able to see my tables or select my schema.

Downloaded the required drivers for presto from tableau download link.

Answer (score 0):

If Tableau has successfully connected then you should be able to see your tables and schema. Are you looking in the correct location? Below is an example where tables would be shown on the Data Source tab (using Teradata as opposed to Presto). [Source via Tableau community from Hari Ankem](https://community.tableau.com/thread/244657)

[image: Image 1]

If you are unable to connect to Presto the following info from Tableau with help you.

> Make the connection and set up the data source
>   Start Tableau and under Connect, select Presto. For a complete list of data connections, select More under To a Server. Then do the following:
>
> Enter the name of the server you want to connect to.
>
> Enter the catalog name.
>
> Select the Authentication method: Username or LDAP, and enter the credentials you're prompted for.
>
> Select the Require SSL check box when connecting to an SSL server.
>
> (Optional) Select Initial SQL to specify a SQL command to run at the beginning of every connection, such as when you open the workbook, refresh an extract, sign in to Tableau Server, or publish to Tableau Server. For more information, see Run Initial SQL.
>
> Select Sign In.
>
> If Tableau can't make the connection, verify that your credentials are correct. If you still can't connect, your computer is having trouble locating the server. Contact your network administrator or database administrator.
>
> On the data source page, do the following:
>
> (Optional) Select the default data source name at the top of the page, and then enter a unique data source name for use in Tableau. For example, use a data source naming convention that helps other users of the data source figure out which data source to connect to.
>
> From the Schema drop-down list, select the search icon or enter the schema name in the text box and select the search icon, and then select the schema.
>
> In the Table text box, select the search icon or enter the table name and select the search icon, and then select the table.
>
> Drag the table to the canvas, and then select the sheet tab to start your analysis.
>
> Use custom SQL to connect to a specific query rather than the entire data source. For more information, see Connect to a Custom SQL Query.

Here is some additional info to consider if your are using a Mac.

> Sign in on a Mac
>   If you use Tableau Desktop on a Mac, when you enter the server name to connect, use a fully qualified domain name, such as mydb.test.ourdomain.lan, instead of a relative domain name, such as mydb or mydb.test.
>
> Alternatively, you can add the domain to the list of Search Domains for the Mac computer so that when you connect, you need to provide only the server name. To update the list of Search Domains, go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced, and then open the DNS tab.

[How to connect Tableau to a Presto database](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_presto.htm)